# How to submit a form to a web page and retrieve content by script

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know how to get contents from a web page which allow different parameter in address link as below:

launch webpage.aspx?PARAMETER=111
{wait for page to load}
retrieve webpage content

launch webpage.aspx?PARAMETER=112
{wait for page to load}
retrieve webpage content

Repeat the steps from PARAMETER from 113 to 120.

Answer (score 0):

in your html you can add

```
<script>
   var qry = window.location.search;
</script>
```

Then qry will be `?PARAMETER=111`
From there you can use regex to split the parameter and value

Take a look at [this SO item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/474535) for more information